# Remote Desktop - Can my company see web browsing in other applications while connected?

Tags: vpn

I access work on my personal mac via a remote desktop connection..I do this on a mac and access it via safari. My question is, can my company then see what I am browsing in Firefox while connected to the remote desktop in safari?

Comment: What dodgy websites are you visiting?

Comment: ha..just the fact that its not work has me worried. can you help put me at ease?

Comment: you've been surfing porn, haven't you?

Comment: nope....just want to be sure about this though. Can you help?

Comment: I'm confused. Is the RDP via a secure web portal on the public Internet, or is there an actual VPN tunnel established first?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the VPN specification you're using. However, if you are connected via VPN you should probably assume that everything you do is visible to the VPN provider if they want it to be. And therefore you should not look at anything the VPN provider would not want you to be looking at, and/or you should trust them to respect your privacy.

If you want to find out where your traffic is traveling, you can open terminal and just type `traceroute cnn.com` (or any website you prefer). This will show you the path your request takes to the resource. It may or may not be easy to recognize your company's servers from this. You can then disconnect VPN and run the same command again and compare the two results.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't really know enough about the specifics but I do know that some VPNs split traffic so that certain requests go through the VPN host, and others pipe all of the traffic through. Most VPNs I've encountered have been the latter type.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did the command and the results seem the same both before and after. Also - ive looked into it and it seems to be connecting via a Secure Virtual Workspace – Juniper SSL. Any further thoughts would be much appreciated. While logged in in Safari i ventured around the internet in Firefox thinking I was protected but am quite worried now.

Comment: @Guest - It sounds like you were using Firefox from your local machine, while connected to the remote machine through Safari. If that's the case, there is nothing to worry about.  Safari set up the remote session completely independent of your local OS. Only activities you do on the remote desktop will be visible to your employer.